# ansible adhoc debug message (Not to run a playbook)

Tags: ansible

I'd like to ask how to show the output of `debug` as if I used `register` using  the `ansible` command, not play a playbook.

For an example, I just to do below, and do a playbook:

> $ ansible  -m raw -a "df -h"

Thank you.

Comment: Ansible uses adhoc command for super quick testing. For debug/ register message you need playbook. Read more about Ad-hoc command here - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to see the output of the command, so instead of using the module raw, use the shell module `-m shell` and it will work.

If you don't specify a module, ansible uses the module `command` so it will works also.

Answer (score 1):

The module shell is missing:

```
$ ansible -m shell raw -a "df -h"
```